# Incomprehensible program speed

Tags: python

I have a ping-pong game with the ability to train a neural network, but the problem is that when I disable the clcok.tick(120) e when training a neural network, my game speeds up very little. I don’t think this is related to optimization because I saw similar ping-pong games with the ability to train a neural network, but when clock.tick() was disabled, their speed increased significantly. What am I doing wrong? The full version of the code is at the link, here is main.py. Help, please

```
import pygame
import sys
import playervsplayer
from block import Player
from ball import Ball
import gl_classes
import map_editor
import neat 
import time
import pickle
import os
from neat import Config, DefaultGenome, DefaultReproduction, DefaultSpeciesSet, DefaultStagnation

class GameInformation:
    def __init__(self, left_hits, right_hits, left_score, right_score):
        self.left_hits = left_hits
        self.right_hits = right_hits
        self.left_score = left_score
        self.right_score = right_score
class MainLoop:
    def __init__(self):
        
        # self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.bg_color = pygame.Color('#2F373F')
        
        pygame.init()
        self.current_res_index = 0

        self.max_ball_speed = 8
        # self.ball_type = "blue_ball"
        self.ball_type = "ball_1"
        self.player_acceleration = 0.3
        self.player_brake = 0.35

        self.font = pygame.font.SysFont('comicsansms', 32)
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080))
        self.middle_strip = pygame.Rect((self.screen.get_width()/2 - 2,12,2,self.screen.get_height()))
        self.accent_color = (27,35,43)
        pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")

        self.menu_items = [
            {"text": "Player vs. Player", "action": self.game_vs_player},
            {"text": "Player vs. Bot", "action": self.game_vs_bot},
            {"text": "Settings", "action": self.settings},
            {"text": "Map editor", "action": self.map_editor},
            {"text": "Enable Neural Network Training", "action": self.enable_nn_training},
        ]
        pygame.mouse.set_cursor(*pygame.cursors.tri_left)
        # Start the main loop
        self.running = True
        self.current_screen = "menu"
        self.main_loop()

    def main_loop(self):
        while self.running:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False
                elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                    if self.current_screen == "menu":
                        self.handle_menu_click(event.pos)
                    elif self.current_screen == "nn_training":
                        self.handle_nn_training_click(event.pos)
                        
            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            if self.current_screen == "menu":
                self.draw_menu()
            elif self.current_screen == "nn_training":
                self.draw_nn_training()

            pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.quit()

    def handle_menu_click(self, pos):
        for i, item in enumerate(self.menu_items):
            text_surface = self.font.render(item["text"], True, (255, 255, 255))
            text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(self.screen.get_width()/2, 100 + i*100))
            if text_rect.collidepoint(pos):
                item["action"]()

    def draw_menu(self):
        for i, item in enumerate(self.menu_items):
            text_surface = self.font.render(item["text"], True, (255, 255, 255))
            text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=(self.screen.get_width()/2, 100 + i*100))
            self.screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)

    def game_vs_player(self):
        opponent = Player('Paddle1.png', 20, self.screen.get_height()/2, 5, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), self.player_acceleration, self.player_brake)
        player = Player('Paddle1.png', self.screen.get_width() - 20, self.screen.get_height()/2, 5, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), self.player_acceleration, self.player_brake)
        

        paddle_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        ball = Ball('ball\small_balls', self.screen.get_width()/2, self.screen.get_height()/2, self.max_ball_speed / 2, self.max_ball_speed / 2, paddle_group, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), self.max_ball_speed, 1.2, self.screen, self.ball_type)
        print(self.max_ball_speed)
        ball_sprite = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
        ball_sprite.add(ball)
        paddle_group.add(player)
        paddle_group.add(opponent)
        
        game_manager = playervsplayer.GameManager(paddle_group, self.screen, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), ball_sprite,pygame.mixer.Sound("pong.ogg"))
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        while True:
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                           
            keys_pressed1 = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            keys_pressed2 = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            player.move(keys_pressed1,1)
            # print(keys_pressed1)
            opponent.move(keys_pressed2,2)
            
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,self.accent_color,self.middle_strip)
            game_manager.run_game()

            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick(120)
            
    def game_vs_bot(self):
        print("Starting game vs. bot")

    def settings(self):
        settings = gl_classes.Settings(self)
        settings.draw_settings()
        self.max_ball_speed = settings.max_ball_speed
        self.ball_type = settings.ball
        self.player_acceleration = settings.player_acceleration
        self.player_brake = settings.player_brake


    def enable_nn_training(self):   
        self.current_screen = "nn_training"
        local_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        config_path = os.path.join(local_dir, 'config.txt')
        config = neat.Config(neat.DefaultGenome, neat.DefaultReproduction,
                            neat.DefaultSpeciesSet, neat.DefaultStagnation,
                            config_path)
        
        self.run_neat(config)
        self.test_best_network(config)

    def run_neat(self, config):
        #p = neat.Checkpointer.restore_checkpoint('neat-checkpoint-85')
        p = neat.Population(config)
        p.add_reporter(neat.StdOutReporter(True))
        stats = neat.StatisticsReporter()
        p.add_reporter(stats)
        p.add_reporter(neat.Checkpointer(1))

        winner = p.run(self.eval_genomes, 50)
        with open("best.pickle", "wb") as f:
            pickle.dump(winner, f)       
        
        
    def test_ai(self, net):
        # clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        run = True
        while run:
            # clock.tick(120)
            player = Player('Paddle1.png', 20, self.screen.get_height()/2, 5, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), self.player_acceleration, self.player_brake)
            bot = Player('Paddle1.png', self.screen.get_width() - 20, self.screen.get_height()/2, 5, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), self.player_acceleration, self.player_brake)
            paddle_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
            paddle_group.add(player)
            paddle_group.add(bot)
            ball = Ball('ball\small_balls', self.screen.get_width()/2, self.screen.get_height()/2, self.max_ball_speed / 2, self.max_ball_speed / 2, paddle_group, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), self.max_ball_speed, 1.2, self.screen, self.ball_type)
            ball_sprite = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
            ball_sprite.add(ball)
            game_manager = playervsplayer.GameManager(paddle_group, self.screen, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), ball_sprite,pygame.mixer.Sound("pong.ogg"))
            game_info = GameInformation(ball.left_hits,ball.right_hits,game_manager.player_score, game_manager.opponent_score)

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    run = False
                    break

            output = net.activate(
                (bot.x_pos, abs(bot.x_pos - ball.x_pos), ball.y_pos))
            decision = output.index(max(output))

            if decision == 1:  # AI moves up
                bot.move_ai('w')
            elif decision == 2:  # AI moves down
                bot.move_ai('s')

            keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            player.move(keys_pressed=keys)

            pygame.display.update()

    def train_ai(self, genome1, genome2, config):
        print("Opening neural network training")
            
        run = True
        start_time = time.time()
            
        net1 = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome1, config)
        net2 = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(genome2, config)
        self.genome1 = genome1
        self.genome2 = genome2
            
        max_hits = 50
            
        bot1 = Player('Paddle1.png', 20, self.screen.get_height()/2, 5, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), self.player_acceleration, self.player_brake)
        bot2 = Player('Paddle1.png', self.screen.get_width() - 20, self.screen.get_height()/2, 5, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), self.player_acceleration, self.player_brake)
        paddle_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
        paddle_group.add(bot1)
        paddle_group.add(bot2)
        ball = Ball('ball\small_balls', self.screen.get_width()/2, self.screen.get_height()/2, self.max_ball_speed / 2, self.max_ball_speed / 2, paddle_group, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), self.max_ball_speed, 1.2, self.screen, self.ball_type)
        ball_sprite = pygame.sprite.GroupSingle()
        ball_sprite.add(ball)
        game_manager = playervsplayer.GameManager(paddle_group, self.screen, self.screen.get_width(), self.screen.get_height(), ball_sprite,pygame.mixer.Sound("pong.ogg"))
        # clock = pygame.time.Clock()   
        while run:
            # clock.tick(12000000000000000000000000000)
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    return True
            self.move_ai_paddles(net1, net2, bot1, bot2, ball)
            self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)
            pygame.draw.rect(self.screen,self.accent_color,self.middle_strip)
            game_manager.run_game_ai()
            game_info = GameInformation(ball.left_hits,ball.right_hits,game_manager.player_score, game_manager.opponent_score)
            pygame.display.flip()
            
            duration = time.time() - start_time
            if game_info.left_score == 1 or game_info.right_score == 1 or game_info.left_hits >= max_hits:
                self.calculate_fitness(game_info, duration)
                break
        return False
                    
        
        
    def move_ai_paddles(self, net1, net2, bot1, bot2, ball):
            
        players = [(self.genome1, net1, bot1, 1), (self.genome2, net2, bot2, 2)]
        for (genome, net, paddle, left) in players:
            output = net.activate(
                (paddle.x_pos, abs(paddle.x_pos - ball.x_pos), ball.y_pos))
            decision = output.index(max(output))
            print(f'left: {left}')
            valid = True
            if decision == 0:  # Don't move
                genome.fitness -= 0.01  # we want to discourage this
            elif decision == 1:  # Move up
            
                if left == 1:
                    print('allah1')
                    # up = pygame.event.Event(pygame.KEYDOWN, {'key': pygame.K_w})
                    
                    valid = bot1.move_ai('w')
                elif left == 2:
                    # print('allah2')
                    # up = pygame.event.Event(pygame.KEYDOWN, {'key': pygame.K_UP})
                    
                    valid = bot2.move_ai('w')
            else:  # Move down
                if left == 1:
                    print('allah3')
                    # up = pygame.event.Event(pygame.KEYDOWN, {'key': pygame.K_s})
                    valid = bot1.move_ai('s')
                elif left == 2:
                    # print('allah4')
                    # up = pygame.event.Event(pygame.KEYDOWN, {'key': pygame.K_DOWN})
                    valid = bot2.move_ai('s')

            if not valid:  # If the movement makes the paddle go off the screen punish the AI
                genome.fitness -= 1

    def calculate_fitness(self, game_info, duration):
        self.genome1.fitness += game_info.left_hits + duration
        self.genome2.fitness += game_info.right_hits + duration
    
    def eval_genomes(self, genomes, config):
        width, height = 1920, 1080
        win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
   

        for i, (genome_id1, genome1) in enumerate(genomes):
            print(round(i/len(genomes) * 100), end=" ")
            genome1.fitness = 0
            for genome_id2, genome2 in genomes[min(i+1, len(genomes) - 1):]:
                genome2.fitness = 0 if genome2.fitness == None else genome2.fitness
                    # pong = PongGame(win, width, height)    
                print(1111) 
                force_quit = self.train_ai(genome1, genome2, config)
                if force_quit:
                    quit()                      
        
    def test_best_network(self, config):
        with open("best.pickle", "rb") as f:
            winner = pickle.load(f)
        winner_net = neat.nn.FeedForwardNetwork.create(winner, config)

        width, height = 1920, 1080
        win = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
        self.test_ai(winner_net) 

    def handle_nn_training_click(self, pos):
        arrow_surface = self.font.render("<", True, (255, 255, 255))
        arrow_rect = arrow_surface.get_rect(topleft=(20, 20))
        if arrow_rect.collidepoint(pos):
            self.current_screen = "menu"

    def draw_nn_training(self):
        self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        arrow_surface = self.font.render("<", True, (255, 255, 255))
        arrow_rect = arrow_surface.get_rect(topleft=(20, 20))
        self.screen.blit(arrow_surface, arrow_rect)
        pygame.draw.rect(self.screen, (255, 255, 255), pygame.Rect(200, 200, 400, 200))

    def map_editor(self):
        editor = map_editor.MapEditor(self)
        editor.draw_interface()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.mixer.init()
    pygame.mixer.music.load('15_Kamski.mp3')
    pygame.mixer.music.play(10000)
    game = MainLoop()
    game.main_loop()
```

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ZlJyMoOve8PvR6OEOeL5Mp8yqV_e47xR?usp=sharing

I removed clock.tick(120) and wrote clock.tick(99999999)

Comment: Google Drive (or other external source)  isn't an acceptable way to share code on Stack Overflow. Please always include relevant code inline in your post.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

`Clock.tick()` is used to limit the speed of your game. If you use `Clock.tick(60)` the program won't go faster than 60 frame a second, but if it struggles to reach 40 fps in the first place, setting the tick rate to 120 or 99999999 won't change anything.

You can find the documentation [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick).